# Something related to Dedekind zeta function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers, $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ its group of units, $\mathcal{Cl}(K)=J_K/P_K$ its ideal class group. As you know, the [Dedekind zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function) is defined as follows:

$$\zeta_{K}(s)=\sum_{I\subseteq \mathcal{O}_K}{\frac{1}{(N_{K/\mathbb{Q} }(I))^{s}}}.$$

---

---

---

Let $\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{Cl}(K)$ be arbitrary, now consider this function:

$$\zeta_{K, \mathcal{A}}^{\text{BAD}}(s)=\sum_{I\subseteq \mathcal{O}_K \\ I \in [\mathcal{A}]}{\frac{1}{(N_{K/\mathbb{Q} }(I))^{s}}}.$$

I did not verify the conditions for absolute convergence, but if there is no serious problem about that, then we have:

$$\zeta_{K}(s) = \sum_{\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{Cl}(K)} \zeta_{K, \mathcal{A}}^{\text{BAD}}(s).$$

---

---

---

$\color{Red}{\text{My question}}$:

I am very curious to know if the **BAD** zeta function $\zeta_{K, \mathcal{A}}^{\text{BAD}}(s)$, is a good thing or not?
What other objects are related to the **BAD** zeta function $\zeta_{K, \mathcal{A}}^{\text{BAD}}(s)$?
I have very little information about this subject, and I could not find anything about it in the literature.
Is there something related to the **BAD** zeta function $\zeta_{K, \mathcal{A}}^{\text{BAD}}(s)$?
Could you please introduce me to some references to follow and read?

Comment: What does "$I\subseteq\mathcal{O}^\times_K$" mean?

Comment: @AnginaSeng +1, you are right. It doesn't make sense. I will edit it now.

Comment: Why **${}$BAD**?

Comment: @AnginaSeng because I don't have enough courage to speak about it, and I thought maybe that function is ridiculous for an expert.

Comment: Your functions are "partial zeta functions". The standard proofs of the analytic class number formula involve using your final sum, and observing that each partial zeta function has a pole at $s=1$ with the same residue.

Comment: See my answer there https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3713036/276986 we decompose $\zeta_K$ this way because the sum over one ideal class is something closeto the Mellin transform of a theta function, from which we obtain the meromorphic continuation, the residues, the functional equation..